# Changing default bake output format and quality

Tags: export, image

Working with 2.68a (r58537).

When I try to export a UV bake, I'm always presented with the format set as `PNG`, it would be amazing to set the default as `JPG`/100% quality. Also when I export to dae (Collada) it always exports them as PNG.
Is there a way to change that default setting?

Comment: forgot to mention that ive set jpg in global settings.

Comment: I tried to make your question a bit clearer. It seems you are asking two questions, though closely related, it may be good to split them.

Answer (score 1):

When saving baking image as an external one, go to UV/Image Editor menu > Save As Image (<kbd>F3</kbd>), pay attention to the left hand tab, there is the place to choose the format you need.

[image: uv save]

As for the Collada export issue, I think it's because you didn't choose to use other format for saving images before that, or didn't even save to an external file. :)

Comment: Thanks Leon, the above screen is what i use to save. What Im looking for is a global setting where its always JPB/100%. On DAE exports one can select to export the UV textures which is what I do, in all cases its the PNG 24BIT. Im looking for the place to set everything to JPG.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I'm afraid there isn't any solution currently without further coding. However, Suppose you really got no internal way in the end, you may consider using external batch image converter (format PNG -> JPG), then rename the extension name in all dae file in batch text editor (text "PNG" -> "JPG") after exporting. I really want to help raising a bounty for you on this question, but I didn't find the entry... So, good luck. :)

Comment: @LeonCheung Bounties are only available after the question has been around for a while. (3 days *IIRC*)

Comment: @gandalf3  Many thanks for the information! :)

Answer (score 0):

To change any default setting, open a new Blender and change only that setting, then go **File > Save Startup File**. This will make Blender open in the state it's in now, including settings, models and preferences, every time.

In your case, simply change the Output render settings (afaik all file dialogs related to images use these settings by default) to what you want:

[image: output settings]

And then save it as the startup file.

[image: startup file]

If you screw anything up accidentally, you can always *Load Factory Settings* from the File menu to revert back to the original default settings.

Comment: Only for renders it seems. (I tested with a AO bake and it was still defaulting to PNG. See my [deleted answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/4861/1))